# Powershell: subtract $pwd from $file.Fullname

Tags: powershell, path, split

Given the following files:

```
c:\dev\deploy\file1.txt
c:\dev\deploy\file2.txt
c:\dev\deploy\file3.txt
c:\dev\deploy\lib\do1.dll
c:\dev\deploy\lib\do2.dll
```

e.g. if $pwd is the following

```
c:\dev\deploy
```

running the statement

```
$files = get-childitem
```

I want to take this list and using `foreach ($file in $files)` I want to substitute my own path for the `$pwd` e.g. I want to print `c:\temp\files` like the following:

```
c:\temp\files\file1.txt
c:\temp\files\file2.txt
c:\temp\files\file3.txt
c:\temp\files\lib\do1.dll
c:\temp\files\lib\do2.dll
```

How can I peform this i.e.

```
A = c:\dev\deploy\file1.txt - c:\dev\deploy\
B = c:\temp\files\ + A

giving B = c:\temp\files\file1.txt
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a cmdlet for that, **Split-Path**, the **-leaf** option gives you the file name. There's also **Join-Path**, so you can try something like this:

```
dir c:\dev\deploy | % {join-path c:\temp\files (split-path $_ -leaf)} | % { *action_to_take* }
```

Comment: This is not what they asked for, they want a recursive solution

Answer (score 6):

I would use filter here and consider piping the files like this:

```
filter rebase($from=($pwd.Path), $to)  {
    $_.FullName.Replace($from, $to)
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\dev\deploy | rebase -from C:\dev\deploy -to C:\temp\files\
Get-ChildItem | rebase -from (Get-Location).path -to C:\temp\files\
Get-ChildItem | rebase -to C:\temp\files\
```

Note that the replacing is case sensitive.

---

In case you would need case insensitive replace, regexes would help:
(*edit based on Keith's comment. Thanks Keith!*)

```
filter cirebase($from=($pwd.Path), $to)  {
    $_.Fullname -replace [regex]::Escape($from), $to
}
```

Comment: The -replace operator allows usage of regexes that are case insensitive e.g. `$_.Fullname -replace [regex]::escape($from),$to`

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
function global:RelativePath
{
    param
    (
        [string]$path = $(throw "Missing: path"),
        [string]$basepath = $(throw "Missing: base path")
    )

    return [system.io.path]::GetFullPath($path).SubString([system.io.path]::GetFullPath($basepath).Length + 1)
}    

$files = get-childitem Desktop\*.*

foreach($f in $files)
{
    $path = join-path "C:\somepath" (RelativePath $f.ToString() $pwd.ToString())
    $path | out-host
}
```

I took the simple relative path from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2006/12/29/powershell-calculating-a-relative-path.aspx) although there is some problems with it, but as you only want to handle paths below your working directory it should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

This works pretty well for me:

```
gci c:\dev\deploy -r -name | %{"c:\temp\$_"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer only works without Sub-Folders

if you need to "convert" Sub-Folders, the Answer of @stej is better.

Here my Version:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.Fullname.Replace('D:\Work\Test\Release', 'C:\temp\files') }
```

Note: .Replace doesn't need to be escaped