# Replace path in Powershell string

Tags: regex, powershell

in my script I check some files and would like to replace a part of their full path with another string (unc path of the corresponding share).

Example:

```
$fullpath = "D:\mydir\myfile.txt"
$path = "D:\mydir"
$share = "\\myserver\myshare"
write-host ($fullpath -replace $path, $share)
```

The last line gives me an error since $path does not not contain a valid pattern for regular expressions.

How can I modify the line to make the replace operator handle the content of the variable $path as a literal?

Thanks in advance,
Kevin

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `[regex]::Escape()` - very handy method

```
$fullpath = "D:\mydir\myfile.txt"
$path = "D:\mydir"
$share = "\\myserver\myshare"
write-host ($fullpath -replace [regex]::Escape($path), $share)
```

You might also use my filter `rebase` to do it, look at [Powershell: subtract $pwd from $file.Fullname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253159/powershell-subtract-pwd-from-file-fullname/2253565#2253565)

Comment: :) When I didn't kwnow about this method the code was complicated (escaping regex sensitive characters by hand). This method pays off ;)

Answer (score 17):

The method `$variable -replace $strFind,$strReplace` understands regex patterns.
But the method `$variable.Replace($strFind,$strReplace)` does not. So try this one.

```
PS > $fullpath.replace($path,$share)
```

\myserver\myshare\myfile.txt